# Modify default find service in Strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi, headless-cms

I have 2 collection types in my Strapi setup: `product` and `review` where a product has many reviews.

I want to add 2 new fields to the response of `/products` and `/products/:id`:

```
averageRaing: number
totalReviews: number
```

I want to override the default `find` service to implement this, but I am unable to find the source code for `strapi.query("product").find(params, populate)` to override it.

If possible, I need this done in a single query rather than making multiple queries.

So far I have:

```js
find(params, populate) {
  return strapi.query("product").model.query(db => {
    // I want the same query as when I run `strapi.query("product").find(params, populate)`
  });
},
```

But I am unsure of how to handle the `params` and `populate` in the exact same way that `.find(params, populate)` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the source code, I found a solution:

```js
const { convertRestQueryParams, buildQuery } = require("strapi-utils");

function find(params, populate) {
  const model = strapi.query("product").model;
  const filters = convertRestQueryParams(params);
  const query = buildQuery({ model, filters });

  return model
    .query((qb) => {
      const totalReviewsQuery = strapi.connections
        .default("reviews")
        .count("*")
        .where("product", strapi.connections.default.ref("products.id"))
        .as("total_reviews");

      const averageRatingQuery = strapi.connections
        .default("reviews")
        .avg("rating")
        .where("product", strapi.connections.default.ref("products.id"))
        .as("average_rating");

      query(qb);

      qb.column("*", totalReviewsQuery, averageRatingQuery);
    })
    .fetchAll({
      withRelated: populate,
      publicationState: filters.publicationState,
    })
    .then((results) => results.toJSON());
}
```